# ValueError: While plotting feature importance using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an array

```
logreg.coef_
```

> array([[ -2.08115860e-01,   3.05150136e-03,   1.43758267e-05]])

While trying to plot it, I am getting value error:

```
pyplot.bar(range(len(logreg.coef_)), logreg.coef_)
pyplot.show()
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Try `logreg.coef_[0]`

Comment: @Dark if I do that will it be considering only the first element in the array?

Comment: or try `logreg.T`

Comment: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'T'

Comment: sorry, mean `logreg.coef_.T`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Regarding the `logreg.coef_[0]`. Yes, it will only consider the first element of the array, but your array has 2 dimensions. The first element is the 1d array of values you want to plot.

Comment: I think the very first comment here is correct. You actually do want to consider only the first element, because it's the only element.

Comment: Your `logreg.coef_` is an array of an array. So to plot the values, you need the index 0. Just use `plt.bar(range(len(logreg.coef_[0])), logreg.coef_[0])`